# iCloud and GEOResourceManifestServerRemoteProxy: Lost connection to geod warning

Tags: iphone, ios, warnings, icloud

I am testing my app that uses `iCloud`. Sometimes, when I fire up the app I get the following warning in the console:

```
GEOResourceManifestServerRemoteProxy: Lost connection to geod
```

Once I get this warning I don't seem to get any data from `iCloud`. I have tried searching this issue, but have found very little information on it.

Any suggestions on how one should try to detect this issue and try to handle it?

Comment: It would help if you at least mentioned which of the iCloud APIs you're using. There are at least four distinct ways to approach it, all with their own requirements and issues.

Comment: I got this warning when I tried to get destination using `CLGeoCoder` and the warning is coming out from this method `- (void)geocodeAddressString:(NSString *)addressString completionHandler:(CLGeocodeCompletionHandler)completionHandler;
`.

Comment: i'm getting this issue also but am only getting the position on the map.

Answer (score 1):

I realize that you asked this back in March, but according to [this](http://support.getsocialize.com/socialize/topics/authenticate_facebook_failed_social_sdk_2_7_1) it can happen when a login (like a connection to FB) has timed out.

If you do a stacktrace and see , then [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12809174/how-to-stop-symbolicate-adding-redacted-pieces-to-ios-crash-log/12854350#12854350) should help.

And [here](http://developer.limneos.net/?framework=GeoServices.framework&header=GEOResourceManifestServerRemoteProxy.h) is the code for that interface, if that's helpful.