# Application crashes after install from Appstore. Google Analytics sent me crash report of instaces <redacted>

Tags: ios, google-analytics

I am struck in some problem. When i Make a AD-Hoc build and run it on My iPhone it don't crash , It also don't crash in simulator and when run on device from Xcode. Infact it never crashed for almost one week before its Release on APPStore.

But after publishing application on App store it crashes giving me this error.

`NSInvalidArgumentException Trace: <redacted> OrderingApp OrderingApp OrderingApp OrderingApp <redacted> <redacted> <redacted> <redacted> <redacted>`

I have enabled `[GAI sharedInstance].trackUncaughtExceptions = YES;`

Has anybody solved it. Need help. Thanks. Highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the debug symbols (dSYM) are removed from the released version of app, and Google Analytics don't have the dSYM, so they could only provide the redacted crash reports.

One possible solution is to check the crash report on iTunes Connect, if there's some reports available, you can download and re-symbolicate them by yourself.

For detailed instruction of re-symbolication, check http://aasims.wordpress.com/2011/05/10/how-to-symbolicate-iphone-crash-reports/ this.

Basically, you will use `symbolicatecrash` command, and you will need dSYM of the released app. You should be able to find the dSYM folder in the archived app (`APP_NAME.xcarchive/dSYMs`).

--

And you can consider integrating with TestFlight SDK which supports auto-symbolication if you provide the dSYM in your next release.

Comment: A note: `<redacted>` will _NOT_ be solved by uploading the apps dSYM! `<redacted>` only appears for iOS system calls.

Comment: ah yes, @Kerni is right, upload dSYM is not going to help with <redacted> ones. But TestFlight should do the symbolicate for you. For more information about "<redacted>", check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12809174/how-to-stop-symbolicate-adding-redacted-pieces-to-ios-crash-log and https://devforums.apple.com/thread/171264