# Fabric/Crashlytics stack trace <redacted> entries

Tags: google-fabric

In some of the crashes I am seeing in Fabric/Crashlytics, the raw text of the stack trace has several entries that are not symbolicated and end up looking like this:

```
10 Foundation                     0x1d351b01 <redacted> + 8
11 Foundation                     0x1d2a7aef <redacted> + 146
12 Foundation                     0x1d299fe7 <redacted> + 770
13 Foundation                     0x1d353d39 <redacted> + 190
```

This answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/12854350/2941876 indicates this can be caused by out-of-date symbol data in ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS\ DeviceSupport.

Is there anything that Fabric support can do to fix this?  Or, anything that I can do when sending dSYM info?

Comment: Mike from Fabric here. This is most often caused by using Bitcode in your app and not sharing symbols with Apple. When the app is recompiled, the dSYMs created by Apple don't have the code needed to symbolicate the crash.

Comment: @MikeBonnell - I am already using all of the recommended settings.  I am using some third-party pods and several of our own private cocoapods.  What specific project settings need to be set in order to make sure the symbols are included?

Comment: There are dozens of potential options, at a minimum, I'd ensure that you're using this: "Include app symbols for your application…" and on the build config that these two "Strip Debug Symbols During Copy" -> NO
"Strip Linked Product" -> NO are set for combined build types.