# Can not get symbols using Frida JavaScript api 'DebugSymbol.fromAddress'

Tags: ios, frida

I'm trying to develop a test tool with ***[Frida](https://www.frida.re/)***. Recently I try the code snippet from the doc to log a backtrace:

```
Interceptor.attach(Module.findExportByName(null, 'open'), {
onEnter: function (args) {
    var path = Memory.readUtf8String(args[0]);
    console.log("open" + path + ")\n\t" + Thread.backtrace(this.context, Backtracer.ACCURATE).map(DebugSymbol.fromAddress).join("\n") + "\n");
}
```

});

but we I try to run the script with my app(**MyApp**), I got these:

```
open/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/E459A8E1-12D5-4E20-8F99-40CA90967C0B/Library/Caches/XXXX/XXXX.plist)
0x1ce3140f Foundation!_NSReadBytesFromFileWithExtendedAttributes
0x1ce356c7 Foundation!-[NSData(NSData) initWithContentsOfFile:options:error:]
0x1cecf0c1 Foundation!+[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:]
0x534293 MyApp!0x4f0293
0x5341f5 MyApp!0x4f01f5
0x53450d MyApp!0x4f050d
0x53360f MyApp!0x4ef60f
0x5346b9 MyApp!0x4f06b9
0x8b4473 MyApp!0x870473
0xb81ecb MyApp!0xb3decb
0xb82225 MyApp!0xb3e225
0xb823bf MyApp!0xb3e3bf
0xb3974d MyApp!0xaf574d
0xb00533 MyApp!0xabc533
0x48039 MyApp!0x4039
0x218595c5 UIKit!-[UIApplication _handleDelegateCallbacksWithOptions:isSuspended:restoreState:]
```

you can see that the

> [DebugSymbol.fromAddress](https://www.frida.re/docs/javascript-api/#debugsymbol)

can symbolicate the address for `Foundation`, but for `MyApp` it failed.

from the ***[video 19:33](https://rmll.ubicast.tv/videos/frida_03038/#slide)***, we can see that the DebugSymbol.fromAddress can symbolicate the address of the target app.

I'm using **Frida 11.0.12** and the **device is iPhone 5 with iOS10.3.3 cracked with h3lix-RC5**.

do anyone also meet this problem?

Answer (score 0):

To reproduce your issue I will need the IPA, or at least `nm -DC` output on MyApp mach0 file.

Also, there is an issue with the script you pasted, `path` is the first element in `args`, it's an address which is a reference to a string, args is an array that contains (not finite) arguments.

```
$ frida -U Telegram
     ____
    / _  |   Frida 11.0.11 - A world-class dynamic instrumentation toolkit
   | (_| |
    > _  |   Commands:
   /_/ |_|       help      -> Displays the help system
   . . . .       object?   -> Display information about 'object'
   . . . .       exit/quit -> Exit
   . . . .
   . . . .   More info at http://www.frida.re/docs/home/

[iOS Device::Telegram]->     Interceptor.attach(Module.findExportByName(null, "open"), {
                                 onEnter: function (args) {
                                     console.log("open " + Memory.readUtf8String(args[0]));
                                     console.log(Thread.backtrace(this.context, Backtracer.ACCURATE).map(DebugSymbol.fromAddress).join
("\n"));
                                 }
                             });
{}
[iOS Device::Telegram]-> open /private/var/mobile/Containers/Shared/AppGroup/1E33CAF6-1422-.../Documents/network-usage
0x10109a8ec Telegram!0x102a8ec
0x1822bd4bc libdispatch.dylib!_dispatch_call_block_and_release
0x1822bd47c libdispatch.dylib!_dispatch_client_callout
0x1822c94c0 libdispatch.dylib!_dispatch_queue_drain
0x1822c0f80 libdispatch.dylib!_dispatch_queue_invoke
0x1822cb390 libdispatch.dylib!_dispatch_root_queue_drain
0x1822cb0b0 libdispatch.dylib!_dispatch_worker_thread3
0x1824d5470 libsystem_pthread.dylib!_pthread_wqthread
open /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/3ED4C762-597B-.../Library/Cookies/Cookies.binarycookies
0x182777dec CoreFoundation!fileOpen
0x182767eb8 CoreFoundation!_CFStreamOpen
0x182777d14 CoreFoundation!CFReadStreamOpen
0x182e578d0 CFNetwork!DiskCookieStorage::readFileToCookies(MemoryCookies*)
```

Comment: you can download myapp from here https://itunes.apple.com/br/app/99/id553663691?mt=8 and thank you for your remind I will correct my script

Answer (score 0):

I think you are observing that your target application doesn't have debug symbols. [These enable these tools to symbolicate memory addresses into a human-readable format](https://www.emergetools.com/blog/posts/symbolicating-swiftui-and-any-apple-framework).

This can also be observed with system library symbols, [where `<redacted>` is being used by iOS when resolving some debug symbols for (parts of) system libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12809174/how-to-stop-symbolicate-adding-redacted-pieces-to-ios-crash-log).

It seems to be more common with newer iOS/Swift applications. Probably best you can do is examine the addresses/binary in a disassembler, e.g., Ghidra or Radare2 to see if they match up with what you expect or get the (debug) symbols of your application and try again.